# Beacon/device that is able to receive signal from another beacon and pass it to smartphone

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, altbeacon, bidirectional, beacon

I've been searching in articles for some simple device that is able to do that(title), but I didnt find any. I am looking for a simple device that is able to get RSSI from some unique beacon in range and then pass it (reveiced RSSI value) to the smartphone(via bluetooth).

I thought about some "smart beacon" that is able to work bidirectional (Get signal from another beacon, then pass it to the smartphone). Has it ever been done?(If yes I would be grateful for any articles).

If I wouldn't find anything I will use another smartphone as that device.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any commercially available products that do this.  A more common solution might be a device that scans for other beacons in the vicinity and reports them directly to a server.

The reason that reporting scanned beacons to a smartphone over BLE isn't a common solution is because it would be simpler for the phone to do the scanning itself.  Why would you need a separate hardware device to do this?

Such a solution you propose might have the advantage of extending the range of the smartphone, but probably not by much.  Consider that if the reliable range of BLE is 40 meters, then a phone 40 meters away from the device you suggest might be able to pick up beacons at most 80 meters away in the same direction.  Practically speaking this would rarely even double the scan area covered by the phone simply working by itself.